In visual studio is it possible to sort the methods by name or any other criteria automatically or by using a menu?
Is it possible to sort functions or methods in Visual Studio Code?
For instance I would like to have all my public methods first, then private one bellow. Then I would like to order them by name. Is there a sunch feature in Visual Studio?

Hi @Bastien, as a workaround, you can use various tool windows, including Class View, Call Hierarchy, Object Browser, and Code Definition to view and sort your code.


Is it possible to sort functions or methods in Visual Studio Code?

Yes, you can use Resharper extension to sort your methods by some criteria.
For example (e.g:c#)
Resharper->Options->Languages->C#->File Layout
Select "All other members" and select "Sort by name".

However, there is no such a menu and build-in function to achieve in visual studio 2022 at present. Only sort usings is supported now.
I suggest you can also raise a feature request from Visual Studio Forum.
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
Update
Just a workaround:
You can view and sort classes and their members in Visual Studio using various tool windows(not in Editor), including Class View, Call Hierarchy, Object Browser, and Code Definition.
For example:
View->Class View
Right click on the class to open Class View shortcut menu.This doc notes:

Sort Alphabetically


Sort by Member Type


Sort by Member Access


